# global `ng version` shows errors instead of version numbers

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Why not showing the installed package versions?

After installed angular cli `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

And checking version `ng --version`

[[image: [screenshot]]

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the @angular/cli package globally with `npm uninstall @angular/cli -g` then install again using `npm install @angular/cli -g`.

Few people got it worked. Issue is being tracked here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10523

Answer (score 0):

Thank [Yakov](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10523#issuecomment-408641405)

Changing directory to one of my project that had node_modules, 
then `ng version` showing the installed package versions correctly.